# ChartControl - Repeated Values on X Axis

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I'm trying to plot a simple chart in a C# windows form application.
The data to plot this chart will be fed run-time.
Problem is it does not plot unique points on the chart with reference to the X-axis values. For example for two points (5,1) and (5,3), it shows the '5' value on the X axis twice.

I tried looking for solutions for similar questions, but none helped.
Here's how my code looks:
(I've purposefully moved the declarations inside the click event handler for easier reference)

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Series series3 = new Series
        {
            Name = "Series3",
            Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red,
            IsVisibleInLegend = false,
            IsXValueIndexed = true,
            ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
        };

        double startPosition = 2;
        double endPosition = 4;

        double startForceLow = 1;
        double startForceHigh = 3;
        double endForceLow = 5;
        double endForceHigh = 7;

        chart1.Series.Clear();
        this.chart1.Series.Add(series3);

        double[] xPoints = { startPosition, startPosition, endPosition, endPosition, startPosition };
        double[] yPoints = { startForceLow, startForceHigh, endForceHigh, endForceLow, startForceLow };

        //Adding individual points too does not work
        //series3.Points.AddXY(startPosition, startForceLow);
        //series3.Points.AddXY(startPosition, startForceHigh);
        //series3.Points.AddXY(endPosition, endForceHigh);
        //series3.Points.AddXY(endPosition, endForceLow);
        //series3.Points.AddXY(startPosition, startForceLow);

        chart1.Series["Series3"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
        chart1.Series["Series3"].YValueType = ChartValueType.Double;

        chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.DataBindXY(xPoints, yPoints);

        chart1.Invalidate();
    }
```

And here is how the chart looks:
[image: ChartControl with repeated values for X-Axis]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you have **told** the chart to **ignore** the `X-Values` and use their **indices** for placing them instead:

```
IsXValueIndexed = true
```

Delete the line or set the property to its **default** `false`!

Result:

[image]

See [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.series.isxvalueindexed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the explanation:

> *True* if the **indices** of data points that belong to the series **will** be
>   used for X-values; *false* if they will **not**. The default value is *false*.

There are rare cases where this is useful, but yours is not one of them. In fact `Line` charts hardly ever are; some charts however make good use of it..:

> All data points in a series use sequential indices, and if this
>   property is true then data points will be plotted sequentially,
>   regardless of their associated X-values. This means that there will be
>   no "missing" data points.
>   ...
>   ...
>   This is useful when you do not want to have missing data points for
>   intervals that you know you will not have data for, such as weekends.
>
> Important
>
> If you are displaying multiple series and at least one series uses indexed X-values, then all series must be aligned—that is, have the
>   same number of data points—and the corresponding points must have the
>   same X-values.